# how to change session expired on elgg 1.11

Tags: elgg

i have changed 2 to 1 hours, like that

```
public function getActionTokenTimeout() {
    if (($timeout = _elgg_services()->config->get('action_token_timeout')) === null) {
        // default to 2 hours
        $timeout = 1;
    }
    $hour = 60 * 60;
    return (int)((float)$timeout * $hour);
}
```

but still not working

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to edit core files like that, especially that you have exposed config option `action_token_timeout` to do that exact change. If you have it set somewhere else in the code, it will take precedence over default value you just changed. Check your settings for `$CONFIG->action_token_timeout = 1` or similar.

Further read on what should you change and what not: http://learn.elgg.org/en/2.0/guides/dont-modify-core.html

Comment: Can you tell me how I make changes while the file is located on the engine in Elgg?
and can you give a simple example that I can develop it?